# Blockchain block time

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

I'm new to blockchain and I try to understand some basic concepts, but have a question about block forming time. Does any blockchain platforms have any restrictions about time for forming a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bitcoin (and many others), you can take as long as you want to mine a block ([though the block's timestamp must be within 2 hours of the network time](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30595/60443)), the problem comes when you are trying to mine a block which contains old transactions (one's which are no longer valid, i.e. have already been mined/replaced). So, once a block is mined, usually miners will watch for that so they can pull in new transactions and attempt to mine those before the next miner wins.